# Размещение иконок по центру

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как разместить иконки по центру. Спасибо. 
P.S. Прошу прощения, если я неправильно оформил вопрос, первый раз это делаю.

```css
.section-services {
 padding-top: 120px;
 display: flex;
 
 &_content,
 &_pic {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  background-color: #202020;
 }

 &_content {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 70px;
  padding-top: 150px;
  .title {
   @include font-sourcepro;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-end;
   font-size: 36px;
   line-height: 60px;
   color: #fff;
   border-right: 5px solid #e74c3c;
   align-items: center;
   height: 35px;
   padding-right: 20px;
   letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  }
  
  .description-item {
   padding-top: 70px;
   padding-bottom: 25px;


   &_title {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 29px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #e74c3c;
   }
   &_text {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 29px;
    width: 70%;
    float: right;
   }
  }
 }
          &_pic {
          img {
           width: 100%;
              }
          }
}
```

```html
<section class="section-outer section-services">
   <div class="section-services_content">
    <div class="title">OUR SERVICES</div>
    <div class="description-item">
     <div class="description-item_title">WEB DESIGN</div>
     <div class="description-item_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur quam eaque ullam sapiente quia ipsa provident, esse placeat temporibus fugiat, soluta.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="description-item">
     <div class="description-item_title">PRINT DESIGN</div>
     <div class="description-item_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur quam eaque ullam sapiente quia ipsa provident, esse placeat temporibus fugiat, soluta.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="description-item">
     <div class="description-item_title">PHOTOGRAPHY</div>
     <div class="description-item_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur quam eaque ullam sapiente quia ipsa provident, esse placeat temporibus fugiat, soluta.</div>
    </div>
    
   </div>
   <div class="section-services_pic">
    <img src="img/serv_pic.png" alt="serv_pic" />
   </div>
  </section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте через flex

Answer (score 0):

> Прошу прощения, если я неправильно оформил вопрос

Неправильно Вы его оформили. Вы видели, что получается, если Ваш код запустить?

> как разместить иконки по центру

У Вас много много ошибок в выборе подхода вёрстки. Это усложняет центрирование иконок

Иконки можно центрировать, добавив их через псевдоэлемент

```
.description-item::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -85px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Примерный результат

```css
.section-services {
  padding-top: 120px;
  display: flex;
}

.section-services_content,
.section-services_pic {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  background-color: #202020;
}

.section-services_content {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 70px;
  padding-top: 150px;
}

.section-services_content .title {
  @include font-sourcepro;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  border-right: 5px solid #e74c3c;
  align-items: center;
  height: 35px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}

.section-services_content .description-item {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.section-services_content .description-item_title {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 29px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #e74c3c;
}

.section-services_content .description-item_text {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 29px;
  width: 70%;
  float: right;
}

.section-services_pic img {
  width: 100%;
}

.description-item::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -85px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-outer section-services">
  <div class="section-services_content">
    <div class="title">OUR SERVICES</div>
    <div class="description-item">
      <div class="description-item_title">WEB DESIGN</div>
      <div class="description-item_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur quam eaque ullam sapiente quia ipsa provident, esse placeat temporibus fugiat, soluta.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="description-item">
      <div class="description-item_title">PRINT DESIGN</div>
      <div class="description-item_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur quam eaque ullam sapiente quia ipsa provident, esse placeat temporibus fugiat, soluta.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="description-item">
      <div class="description-item_title">PHOTOGRAPHY</div>
      <div class="description-item_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur quam eaque ullam sapiente quia ipsa provident, esse placeat temporibus fugiat, soluta.</div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="section-services_pic">
    <img src="img/serv_pic.png" alt="serv_pic" />
  </div>
</section>
```